# How do I get and set data from redis in Go?

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

```
var rdb *redis.Client
var ctx = context.Background()


    rdb = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6379",
        Password: "", // no password set
        DB:       0,  // use default DB
    })

// set for 24 hours
err := rdb.Set(ctx, topics, data, 86400).Err()

// err is nil

val, err := rdb.Get(ctx, topics).Result()

// val is empty
```

when i check redis manually there's nothing there.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps check the reply from the `Set` call https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/working-with-redis

Comment: err is empty no error visible.

Comment: my only guess is its expiring immediately.

Comment: The value expires in 86.4µs.

Answer (score -5):

cannot use integers for time

`24 * time.Hour` works but `86400` does not.

Comment: Integers work just fine. 86400 means 86400 *nanoseconds* -- https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants

Comment: ahh ok i thought redis only excepted seconds. in every other library it's seconds.

Comment: it's less about Redis, more about how Go represents time.

Comment: If you look at the documentation, the expiration argument will be a `time.Duration`